# Is it possible to use a variable as part of a range in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I basically want to fill all the used cells from row 8 onwards in column H with a formula. I have the number of the last row calculated, and have tried applying the value like so:

```
Range("H8:HlastRow").Value = "=(RC[+1])*(RC[+2])"
```

but no luck. Is there a way to make this work, and if so what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the variable like this:

```
Range("H8:H" & lastRow).Value = "=(RC[+1])*(RC[+2])"
```

Comment: If you do it like you did, excel will see Hlastrow as a "textstring"

Comment: Should be `Range("H8:H" & lastRow)`